# PowerShell: How to retrieve a specific property _exclusively_

Tags: active-directory, powershell

How can I retrieve a specific property **exclusively**?

I am aware of the `select-object` cmdlet which seems to be dowdy in that respect:

```
PS C:\> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=Houston,DC=contoso,DC=net' -Filter 'Name -like "SomeOU"' -Properties * | Select-Object Description,Streetaddress,State,postalcode | format-list
```

An optimized version would be:

```
PS C:\> Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase 'OU=Houston,DC=contoso,DC=net' -Filter 'Name -like "SomeOU"' -Properties Description,Streetaddress,State,postalcode
```

Why is the `-property` switch not solely returning the entered propteries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because the `-properties` switch is not a formatting tool, it is intended as a way to receive more information than the default values already included.

From the [Get-ADOrganizationalUnit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617236.aspx) article.

> Specifies the properties of the output object to retrieve from the server. Use this parameter to retrieve properties that are not included in the default set.

If you want to format your output, you're better of sticking with the `select-object` statement.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to use both, to specify which properties to *retrieve* from the DC, and which ones to select and ultimately display. `-Properties *` is a potential performance basher since the DSA will need to return *every* attribute that has a value, including certificates and other binary values you might not have need for

In a script utilizing the AD cmdlets I would use the [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx) operator (`@`) and do the following:

```
$ADSplat = @{
    "SearchBase" = 'OU=Houston,DC=contoso,DC=net'
    "Filter"     = 'Name -eq "SomeOU"'
    "Properties" = "Description","Streetaddress","State","postalcode"
}
$ADOU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit @ADSplat | Select-Object $ADSplat["Properties"]
```

If you do this consistently, your scripts become über-easy to update/edit, since every query is defined in the same readable hastable format

---

If I'm at the shell and mid-oneliner come to think about the properties I need, I'd do something like (using `Get-ADUser` as an example):

```
Get-ADUser username -Properties ($p = "manager","memberOf","cn") |select $p
```

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using LDAP or ADSI http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/12/01/use-powershell-to-query-active-directory-from-the-console.aspx